# Issues setting up ASP.Net Role Provider + EF 7

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Long story, originally a project was started using Azure AD auth as the authentication for the application, approaching the end of the project we noticed the huge flaws Azure auth had *(Normal Users where not able to authenticate)*

So the decision was made to move from Azure auth to ASP Identity Auth. To do this a new web project was created and all of the data from the first project was placed into it by coping the files from one project to another.

This caused a few headaches but eventually got everything going. With the new project it came with a Migration and **ApplicationDBContext** already to handle all of the ASP tables. This was the first issue as we already had a very detailed **DbContext** but using command line we managed to run all the migrations correctly.

Now we are presented with a new issue, every time we launch the application in **VS2015** the error:

> The Error:
>
> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Musted.Models.ApplicationDbContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore`3[Musted.Models.ApplicationUser,Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole,Musted.Models.ApplicationDbContext]'.

I believe the issue is somewhere in the **Startup.cs** with how the identity is created.

**Existing Context:** ProjectContext.cs
**New ASP Auth Context:** ApplicationDBContext.cs

> Startup.cs <-> Where I believe the issue to be

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
            services.AddEntityFramework()
                .AddSqlServer()
                .AddDbContext<ProjectContext>();
            services.AddScoped<ProjectContextSeedData>();

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
        services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();
    }



    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, MusteredContextSeedData seeder)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseBrowserLink();
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");

            try
            {
                using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>()
                    .CreateScope())
                {
                    serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>()
                         .Database.Migrate();
                }
            }
            catch { }
        }

        app.UseIISPlatformHandler(options => options.AuthenticationDescriptions.Clear());

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseIdentity();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

> ApplicationDBContext.cs

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        var connString = Startup.Configuration["Data:ProjectContextConnection"];
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connString);

        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {

        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
}
```

> ProjectContext.cs

```
 public class ProjectContext: DbContext
{
    public ProjectContext()
    {
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users {get; set;}
    public DbSet<UserLevel> UserLevels { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ApprovalStatus> ApprovalStatus { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Area> Areas { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Company> Company { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Event> Events { get; set; }
    public DbSet<LeaveType> LeaveTypes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Leave> Leave { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Shift> Shifts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserLoginAudit> UserLoginAudit { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserType> UserType { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ShiftDay> ShiftDay { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        var connString = Startup.Configuration["Data:ProjectContextConnection"];
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connString);

        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }


}
```

**UPDATE**

So after some more digging, I have found the line in the ASP generated code that is failing.

```
private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager; 
//This is the line that is erroring
var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

That calls is all throughout the ASP stuff so I am guessing nothing will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end - I deleted the project and imported the classes from the start. I wasted hours trying to get it working the other way and the new project was just much quicker.